# Error Message when Running Azure Automation Runbook

Tags: powershell, azure-storage, azure-automation

I'm trying to create an Azure Automation Runbook to write messages to an existing Azure Storage Queue using information from a SQL Query.  The below works perfectly in Powershell ISE on my Windows 10 machine, but I'm getting an error when testing it in Azure the Automation.

The script is:

```
Connect-AzureRmAccount
Get-AzureRmSubscription
Set-AzureRmContext -SubscriptionId <our subscription id>

$resourceGroup = "our resource group"
$storageAccountName = "our storage account name"
$queueName = "our queue name"
$queue = Get-AzureRmStorageQueueQueue -resourceGroup $resourceGroup -storageAccountName $storageAccountName -queueName $queueName

$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection

$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "our Azure SQL connection string"

$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand

$SqlCmd.CommandText = $("SELECT SourceId FROM dbo.batches GROUP BY SourceId HAVING SourceId > 101")

$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection

$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter

$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd

$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet

$Table = new-object system.data.datatable

$SqlAdapter.Fill($Table) | out-null

$SqlConnection.Close()

$compArray = @($Table | select -ExpandProperty SourceId)

 foreach ($array in $compArray) {
 Add-AzureRmStorageQueueMessage -queue $queue -message @{"SourceId"=$array;"RetryCount"=0;}
 }
```

Again, this works perfectly in Powershell on my local machine, but in Azure Automation, I get this error:

```
Failed
Queue <our queue name> could not be retrieved/created from Storage Account <our storage account> on resource group  (Queue <our queue name> could not be retrieved/created from Storage Account <our storage account> on resource group )

Set-AzureRmContext : Run Connect-AzureRmAccount to login.
At line:3 char:1
+ Set-AzureRmContext -SubscriptionId <our subscription id> ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Set-AzureRmContext], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.SetAzureRMContextCommand

Get-AzureRmStorageAccount : No subscription found in the context.  Please ensure that the credentials you provided are 
authorized to access an Azure subscription, then run Connect-AzureRmAccount to login.
At C:\Modules\User\AzureRmStorageQueue\AzureRmStorageQueueCoreHelper.psm1:86 char:19
+ ... aContext = (Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGro ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzureRmStorageAccount], ApplicationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Management.Storage.GetAzureStorageAccountCommand

Get-AzureStorageQueue : Could not get the storage context.  Please pass in a storage context or set the current storage 
context.
At C:\Modules\User\AzureRmStorageQueue\AzureRmStorageQueueCoreHelper.psm1:88 char:94
+ ... ue]$queue = Get-AzureStorageQueue -Name $queueName -Context $saContex ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzureStorageQueue], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.Queue.GetAzureStorageQueueCommand

New-AzureStorageQueue : Could not get the storage context.  Please pass in a storage context or set the current storage 
context.
At C:\Modules\User\AzureRmStorageQueue\AzureRmStorageQueueCoreHelper.psm1:92 char:95
+ ... ue]$queue = New-AzureStorageQueue -Name $queueName -Context $saContex ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureStorageQueue], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.Queue.NewAzureStorageQueueCommand
```

Could someone assist me in what I'm missing here?  (I have confirmed that the AzureRmStorageQueue module is installed in Azure Automation.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the azure runbook, no need to use the interactive login, if you create an automation account, it will create a service principal and add it to your subscription as a contributor role automatically. So you just need to use the service principal to do what you need.

The command should be like as below, you could try it.

```
$connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
try
{
    # Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "
    $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         

    "Logging in to Azure..."
    Add-AzureRmAccount `
        -ServicePrincipal `
        -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
        -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
        -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint 
}
catch {
    if (!$servicePrincipalConnection)
    {
        $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
        throw $ErrorMessage
    } else{
        Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
        throw $_.Exception
    }
}

$resourceGroup = "our resource group"
$storageAccountName = "our storage account name"
$StorageAccountKey = (Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -AccountName $storageAccountName).Value[1]
$context=New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $StorageAccountKey
$queueName = "our queue name"
$queue = Get-AzureRmStorageQueueQueue -resourceGroup $resourceGroup -storageAccountName $storageAccountName -queueName $queueName -Context $context

$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection

$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "our Azure SQL connection string"

$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand

$SqlCmd.CommandText = $("SELECT SourceId FROM dbo.batches GROUP BY SourceId HAVING SourceId > 101")

$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection

$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter

$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd

$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet

$Table = new-object system.data.datatable

$SqlAdapter.Fill($Table) | out-null

$SqlConnection.Close()

$compArray = @($Table | select -ExpandProperty SourceId)

 foreach ($array in $compArray) {
 Add-AzureRmStorageQueueMessage -queue $queue -message @{"SourceId"=$array;"RetryCount"=0;}
 }
```

Comment: Works perfectly, Joy.  Thanks!